# (iOS/macOS) Image (Laplacian) Pyramid storage and HEIC/HEIF

Tags: ios, image-processing, zooming, smooth-scrolling, heif

The context is this: I will be storing several sizes of a given image for zooming purposes, as well as system efficiency (energy & space).

After all these years, I still haven't seen a regular use-case for indexed images in CF other than that the index at zero is almost always interpreted as the image thumbnail, with the full-sized image to follow.

HEIF is a structured file type, and is extensible in a way that would allow Laplacian or Gaussian pyramids to be stored even without trampling on the tilesets that Apple uses internally, but the desired outcome here is to smoothly scale up from something quite small (outermost view in iOS Photos app, for example), up to beyond full screen.

So I'm asking what the canonical approach is to this, or even the de facto use, or if there's some other way of doing deep zooming that I haven't found after extensive looking?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is CF please?

Comment: CF == CoreFoundation  It's a non-OO layer below Foundation (but this is changing).